# In Django, is it possible to access the current user session from context of parent template within a inclusion tag?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-custom-tags

As we know, if we want to access user session from context within a inclusion tag, you can use `takes_context` argument and pass a request context in the view.

But in my project, it is more complicated:

The view is simple:

```
# views.py
def index(request):
    form = PersonForm()
    return render(request, 'add.html', {'form': form})
```

Templates:

```
# templates/add.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Person</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </form>
        {% render_attachments %}
        ...
    </body>
</html>

# templates/list.html
{% load my_tags %}
<div class="attachments" style="margin:12px 0 12px 0;">
    {% for attachment in attachments %}
        <a href="{{ attachment.attachment_file.url }}">{{ attachment.filename }}
        </a>
        {% attachment_delete_link attachment %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here is my custom tags:

```
# my_tags.py

@register.inclusion_tag('attachments/list.html', takes_context=True)
def render_attachments(context):
    session = context['request'].session
    return {'attachments': session.get('attachments', [])}

@register.inclusion_tag('attachments/delete_link.html', takes_context=True)
def attachment_delete_link(context, attachment):
    if context['user'] == attachment.creator:
       return {
           'delete_url': reverse('delete_attachment', 
                                 kwargs={'attachment_pk': attachment.pk})
    }
    return {'delete_url': None}
```

When i run my project, i got the following error:

```
KeyError at /person/
'user'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/person/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: KeyError
```

So, i print context out within two tags to find out what happened, it seemed that the request context does not passed into `attachment_delete_link`, how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: You have `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`?

Comment: Yes, i can get user in first tag `render_attachments`, but in the second layer, the user seemed to be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the whole context in `render_attachments()` you must return

```
def render_attachments(context):
    # some code...
    context['attachments'] = session.get('attachments', [])
    return context
```

Same goes for `attachment_delete_link()`.